# Why do I always get this exception?

Tags: java, exception, actionlistener, joptionpane

I developed an app with a GUI, with buttons, relative actionListeners, and exceptions. 
Today I had this problem. In an `actionEvent` relative to a button of my GUI, I inserted this code, with some `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

 if(ae.getSource()==b1){
 try{//FIRST `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`
   int load = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert current load value: "));
   auto.setCurrentLoad(load);
   //other `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`
 int choiceDep = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Does the truck transport perishable goods? 1: YES 2: NO"));
 if(choiceDep==1) {
   //here we have to insert expiration date
   int day = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert value"));
  int month = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert value"));
  int year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert value"));
  auto.setPerishable(day,month,year);
 }
 else if(choiceDep==2) 
                 auto.setNotPerishable();

String choiceAv = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Available Truck? Yes or no?");
 if(choiceAv.equals("Yes")) auto.setAvailable();
 else auto.setNotAvailable();

}
        //the exception      
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Exception!");}             
  }
```

Where `setAvailable, setNotAvailable,setPerishable,setCurrentLoad` are methods of the external class, with reference `auto`.

When I execute this code, it appears the GUI, then I click on button `b1`. It appears the first `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, to insert a value stored in a `int load`.

I entered a value, but no other `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` appeared (but there are other input dialog) and I got the exception in the command-line. 
I noticed that the value inserted in the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is never passed to the line `auto.setCurrentLoad(load);`.

Why does it happen? Never seen this error before. Why do I always get the exception immediately after the first `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` Maybe the JVM doesn't accept many of this `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` in the same statement/method? Or maybe(as I think) is a programming error of mine?

Thanks for your help. Cheers.

EDIT: I forgot to insert the exception I got in the command-line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at AutoCom.actionPerformed(AutoCom.java:50)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown So
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the Exception you are getting.  You should change your catch block from `System.out.println...` to `e.printStackTrace();`.  This will print out the full exception.  Please update your post with the stack trace.

Comment: @bmargulies This is, appearing in the command-line: System.out.println("Exception!"); After, the other code is not executed..

Comment: You need to debug. So you need to run in a debugger and look at the exception, and see what exception it is. When you find out, post it here, you might get help.

Comment: @bmargulies Sorry, this is the exception: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @Ryan Gross An error of mine. I forgot to print the exception with the code you suggest.

Comment: Well, it will also tell you what line of your source got an NPE, and that will probably tell you what happened.

Comment: @bmargulies Now, I try fo fix it!!

Comment: @MirroredFate Line 50? Be more accurate, I posted code with less of 50 lines. In my complete class, on line 50 I had auto.setCurrentLoad(load); auto is declared as private Auto auto;

Comment: I fixed the problem, incredible error, forgotten the initialization object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the `auto` object is not initialized before you pressed the button.  I'm assuming `auto` is a member variable of the `AutoCom` class.  In that case, you should probably change the `auto` definition to:

```
protected <TypeOfAutoHere> auto = new <TypeOfAutoHere>();
```

Comment: I fixed. I forgot to initialize the object, without changing "private" to "protected"

Comment: Thanks to you, with a lot a lines of code I forgotten this important thing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it looks like the auto variable is null.

Comment: But I declared first in the class AutoCom as: "private Auto auto" where "Auto" is an external class.

Comment: Ok. It's just you said. I fixed. Thank you.